# What is difference using enum class variables in main and other callable in c++?

Tags: c++, enums

1

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

enum class Widget;
using UType = underlying_type_t<Widget>;
UType getWidget();

int main() {
    cout<<getWidget();
    cout<<static_cast<int>(Widget::a);
    return 0;
}

UType getWidget() {
    return static_cast<UType<Widget>>(Widget::a);
}

enum class Widget {
    a, b, c
};
```

2

```
#include<iostream>
#include<type_traits>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
using UType = underlying_type_t<T>;

enum class Widget;

template<typename T>
UType<T> getWidget();

int main() {
    cout<<getWidget<Widget>();
    //cout<<static_cast<int>(Widget::a);
    return 0;
}

template<typename T>
UType<T> getWidget() {
    return static_cast<UType<Widget>>(Widget::a);
}


enum class Widget {
    a, b, c
};
```

When I used Widget::a in main, compiler failed because of "Undefined identifier Error". But, when I called GetWidget, this code was compiled.
What is difference in two situations?

---2 is working if I use getWidget(). but 1 isn't.
---compiler : visual studio 2019 iso c++14 standard
---error message :

1. c2027 : use of undefined type 'Widget'
2. C2065 : 'a' : undeclared identifier

Comment: `But, when I called GetWidget, this code was compiled. What is difference in two situations?` Could you please post a separate code snippet with the code that was compiled? You call the function in the code you posted, and it did not compile - there's a contradiction. I do not believe `UType<Widget>` given `UType = underlying_type_t<Widget>;` would compile. Are you sure you are using this source file?

Answer (score 1):

You need to *define* `enum class Widget` before you can use any of the enumerators (`Widget::a`). You have the definition below everything else, where it invisible to everything else and therefore useless. The declaration is visible, but a mere declaration is not enough to use the enumerators. It is only enough to use the name of the enumeration itself (`Widget`).

MSVC does not detect the error in `getWidget` because its handling of templates is not standards compliant. Its implementation of the two-phase lookup is incomplete and is not enabled by default. If you enable it with a compiler switch, it is still incomplete. It seems to be broken for qualified names, which are not looked up in the first phase. That is, if you write `x::y` in a template, MSVC looks up `x` in the first phase (and complains if it is not defined), but ignores `y`. Other compilers [do not have this bug](https://godbolt.org/z/T5Gnqzncc).

If you make `getWidget` a non-template, which it should have been in the first place, MSVC [will complain](https://godbolt.org/z/s1b7xaTPv).

Comment: if so, why getWidget() is worked well? Widget is defined blow getWidget() definition..

Comment: @yeongro [it didn't](https://godbolt.org/z/djh5TPrW7). If you have a version where `getWidget` works, post a [mcve] together with a complete and unedited set of compiler messages.

Comment: Can I post format like compiler : visual studio 2019 iso c++ 14 standard, not error message(call getWidget), error messages(call a in main), C2027-Use undefined type Widget and 'a' is undefined identifier?

Comment: @yeongro please edit your question and include the exact source file(s) and the **complete unedited error messages** for each separate run of the compiler. Error messages should be formatted as code.

Comment: I can't find how to upload code.. sorry, but, code block 2 is same code..

Comment: @yeongro No worries, I have updated my answer to explain the problem with MSVC.

Comment: Thank you very very much!! :) have a good weekend!!